# Manually set ssh host keys on server / Digital Ocean Droplet

Tags: security, ssh, digital-ocean, cloud-init

I want to do the following:

1. Create Digital Ocean droplets from my development machine (to distribute my tests, which are taking too long).
2. Securely issue a commands to the droplet.
3. Destroy the droplet.

I'm stuck on #2. I can successfully create the droplets through the Digital Ocean API, and I can set my SSH key in the `authorized_keys` area, but if I allow Digital Ocean to create the key then I have no way of verifying the server's public key.

Now normally if this were within the same data centre, it wouldn't be a concern, since I could rely on Digital Ocean not implementing a MITM attack because they have root anyway, but since I'm connecting from my development machine I need a way of trusting the public key.

I've tried following various cloud-init guides, but I always get the error:

```
ssh root@178.62.69.133
Connection closed by 178.62.69.133
```

I've tried to eliminate any possibility for error, I've even resorted to base64 encoding the private key, thinking that there might be some escaping issue.

This is the command I use to create the keys:

```
e = "ssh-keygen -t ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 -f #{loc} -q -N #{password} -C \"\""
system(e)
```

Which expands to this:

```
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 -f /tmp/testing-60f42fcf -q -N 77924d8f4fa12a365c8c003ca091f5ad6a2c4c22 -C ""
```

I then base64 encode it,

```
private_key = `base64 --wrap=0 #{loc}`.chomp
public_key = `base64 --wrap=0 #{loc}.pub`.chomp
```

and place it into the cloud-init yaml file (didn't want to use `|` because it is a special character in Yaml, and I wanted to avoid it if possible):

```
#cloud-config
---
runcmd:
- echo test > /root/test
- rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host*
- echo LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBFQyBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tClByb2MtVHlwZTogNCxFTkNSWVBURUQKREVLLUluZm86IEFFUy0xMjgtQ0JDLEY3MDNDNzM1QTAxQzgyNEVBRjhCODA4NkVDREIyMjAwCgpiYlpCa3A2Ujcyd1RRNUsyL2w4QW9YU3FQNllRVjV0aVJETytmU1FqZTlEUjY4MG9wY3RCRGhKRWdPQ0prSkw1CmhOUGxydzUveHFwTHM5UXc3cWJaWlUvRHR0YnlxZTFWUDcyVHBRS1pFL2FDcTdGTWFpbFJrcUpFa3JobVdCcFEKbWtQTW15M3BwVFZZKzJvRDZTdmMzdzZyTW1JTlpKUkltRUxiUk81S2M4bz0KLS0tLS1FTkQgRUMgUFJJVkFURSBLRVktLS0tLQo=
  > /tmp/base64_pri && base64 --decode /tmp/base64_pri > /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
- echo ZWNkc2Etc2hhMi1uaXN0cDI1NiBBQUFBRTJWalpITmhMWE5vWVRJdGJtbHpkSEF5TlRZQUFBQUlibWx6ZEhBeU5UWUFBQUJCQkVHSDJBS3BVcVE0NVZQWGNFK3h5NXV6elVnajhKelBxODJNaERLV0szaGltUVBReWRPQ0RlRVdyRVJzeCtUTEtPSjBlRElJWU9jT2RWT0FteHZycG1nPSAK
  > /tmp/base64_pub && base64 --decode /tmp/base64_pub > /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
- sleep 1 && service ssh restart
```

(Don't worry, that ssh key / droplet has been destroyed, this is for demonstration purposes)

I can verify that when I leave out the rest of the commands that the `echo test > /root/test` runs successfully. I've also tested this on my local machine and the md5sums match:

```
028760a9374f9abd9c2c66eceb20f245  /tmp/pub_key_check
028760a9374f9abd9c2c66eceb20f245  /tmp/testing-60f42fcf.pub

2bf65516aaef01c731d061fa4ba788c5  /tmp/pri_key_check
2bf65516aaef01c731d061fa4ba788c5  /tmp/testing-60f42fcf
```

So I know I'm decoding them correctly.

I've tried other key types, but I'd like to use ecdsa keys if possible, because it is the default for my other boxes. What am I doing wrong here? Also, am I the only one doing this? I've Google around and it looks like the common answer is that people just auto-trust the generated public key which I think is insane if you are doing this cross data centre since any random ISP (or, in my case, cafe) could passively MITM you.

Comment: There is no such type as `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256`. In manual page, there is selection from `[-t dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa | rsa1]` (at least on my ubuntu).

Comment: @Jakuje Thanks for the idea, but changing ti to `ecdsa` or `rsa` does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have determined the solution!

Two mistakes were made. The first was this:

```
e = "ssh-keygen -t ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 -f #{loc} -q -N #{password} -C \"\""
```

Adding a password is something I do out of habit, but of course the machine didn't know the password in the first place! so the `-N #{password}` bit should be removed to just this:

```
e = "ssh-keygen -t ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 -f #{loc} -q -C \"\""
```

The second error was that I didn't set the permissions on the key! So the following two commands were added:

```
- chmod 600 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
- chmod 644 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
```

to the `runcmd`

I really wish that Digital Ocean would just return the keys. If you think so too upvote it here: https://digitalocean.uservoice.com/forums/136585-digitalocean/suggestions/9307569-return-the-droplet-s-ssh-public-key-as-part-of-api

Thanks to @shazow for asking me the right questions :)